# form select option line break overlap

Tags: css

I have a standard select> option> form element but on some screens the option> is breaking to a second line.  Is there a way to force it to NOT break OR at least control the line height to avoid it overlapping with the first line?

I've tried the usual suspects ex. line-height:60px; etc. but no luck?

Comment: when asking such question, could you also add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your breaking string contains whitespaces. To string not to break use non-breakable-space `&nbsp;` HTML special character instaed of whitespaces in your `<option>` value string;